# Python why is parenthesis printing on next line stdin and stdout

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to figure out why the output for my data prints like the below.  I am completely stumped can someone point out to me why the parenthesis is printing on the next line?

High level this code is supposed to take in input like:
C;M;my func

and print to stdout something like: myFunc()

however it's shoving my parenthesis to the next line and I do not see what I am missing here.  Probably something basic...

The problem I'm solving for interview prep purposes is supposed to take in input from stdin and output to stdout.

Input given to code is:

C;M;mouse pad

C;C;code swarm

[image]

```
# Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT
import sys


def split(line, inputType):
    words = []
    curStart = 0

    for i in range(len(line)):
        if line[i].isupper() and i != curStart:
            words.append(line[curStart:i].lower())
            curStart = i

    if inputType == 'M':
        words.append(line[curStart:-2].lower())
        word = " ".join(words)
        return word

    words.append(line[curStart:].lower())
    word = " ".join(words)
    return word


def combine(line, inputType):
    tempArr = []
    lineData = line.split(" ")

    for i in range(len(lineData)):
        if (inputType == 'M' and i == 0) or inputType == 'V':
            tempArr.append(lineData[i])
        else:
            tempArr.append(lineData[i][0].upper() + lineData[i][1:])
    if inputType == 'M':
        tempArr.append('()')

    word = "".join(tempArr)

    return word


res = []
for line in sys.stdin:
    action = line[0]
    inputType = line[2]

    if action == 'S':
        word = split(line[4:], inputType)
        res.append(word)
    else:
        word = combine(line[4:], inputType)
        res.append(word)

for i in res:
    sys.stdout.writelines(i)
```

Comment: If you print `lineData` you will see this `['mouse', 'pad\n']`. So the word you return is `mousePad\n()`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again mx0.  I think the answer to this for me is to question your input format and to not grow complacent if things like LeetCode and hackerNet get you used to expecting clean input.